# Setting up a private tor bridge on windows

Tags: windows

I need to set up a private Tor Bridge on Port 80 to bypass censored connections. How do I go through this process on windows?

Comment: https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges#RunningABridge

Comment: You better use port 443 for ORPort, 80 for DirPort and - if you need a bridge - use port 443 **with** Obfs3/4 transport for bridge port and 1080 for ORPort. Use `tor.exe` with `-f /path/to/config/file` flag to run it as a service for your bridge. need further help?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to download [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) and install it. Once the installation is complete, launch the Tor Browser you will be presented with a window as shown below. Click the second button that says "Configure".

[image]

In the next screen slick "yes" and then "Next"

[image]

In the following windows, the default configurations should work in most cases, so keep clicking "next" (or change settings as per your wish - especially the one about the local proxy).

Sometimes you will have to wait until a connection is made.

[image]

Comment: I meant to host a relay for my own use away from home.